# Error: "could not find function "lengths"

Tags: r, lme4

While running:

```
 reg_model = glmer(modeling1 ~ pTOT_VIOPT_CT + (1|STUDY_CODE_ALIAS),
                  data=data_CACZ, family=binomial)
```

I am getting the error:

```
Error in .fixupDimnames(.Object@Dimnames) : 
  could not find function "lengths"
```

Not sure what could be the possible reason.

FYI: I am putting below the `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.11.5  lme4_1.1-10  Matrix_1.2-3 car_2.0-21   MASS_7.3-29 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-29 minqa_1.2.4     nlme_3.1-118    nloptr_1.0.4    nnet_7.3-7      splines_3.0.2   tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: `lengths` was introduced in R 3.2.0 - check out `news(Version == "3.2.0" & grepl("lengths", Text))`, please update your R version.

Comment: What @DavidArenburg said or define `lengths<-function(x) vapply(x,length,1L)`.

Comment: @nicola That function is still much slower than the compiled `lengths` function, so probably updating the version will be better still

Comment: @DavidArenburg Of course. But it could be a temporary work-around if OP wants to see quickly if their code works before reinstalling. No doubt that medium/long run an update is better. Also, the `news` bit is useless if OP has an old version (nothing will be shown, tested on R-3.1.0).

Comment: @nicola nice catch there :) Haven't thought of that.

Comment: OP, I think you have something strange in your installation, since the function `.fixupDimnames` is in the `Matrix` package and exists only for recent R versions. So you have a too updated (relative to R) `Matrix`, which is very strange. Update R soon.

Comment: Digging further, I notice that the `Matrix` package declares to depend on `R (≥ 3.0.1)`. It's wrong, since it uses `lengths`. I'm going to contact the maintainer.

Answer (score 5):

(From the maintainer of 'Matrix'):  This is indeed really strange,
but differently than @nicola suggests.

1. It is okay to update Recommended packages such as Matrix without updating R.  That's indeed one **feature** of these.
2. Matrix 1.2-3 is indeed the current version of Matrix on CRAN, which is good.

However, since Matrix 1.2-2, there is the following code  in Matrix/R/zzz.R :

```
if(getRversion() >= "3.2.0") {
    ......
} else {
    ......
    lengths <- function (x, use.names = TRUE) vapply(x, length, 1L, USE.NAMES = use.names)
}
```

But that code only works correctly for you, when the Matrix package is *built* from the source with a correct version of R, i.e. in your case with a version of R before 3.2.0.
This (correctly built) happens for all platforms but Windows (the *broken by choice* one).

If you really don't want (or can't easily) upgrade your version of R,
you have two other options:

1. downgrade your version of Matrix to the one that comes with your version of R.  As you probably have installed the new Matrix replacing the old one, you need to get that and replace the newer version of Matrix.  HOWEVER, I guess you would also have to downgrade lme4, and in the end you suffer too much.
2. Safer and in principle correct: Install the 'Rtools' collection for Windows (you need the one that matches your version of R !)
   including C compiler etc, until the following works correctly

   ```
   install.packages("Matrix", type = "source")
   ```

The work to do this may well be worth it.  You will be able to install other R packages from their source, which is very useful anyway
(I would not want to live without this possibility if I had to work with Windows).